# How to mousewheel zoom the whole desktop in ubuntu budgie

Tags: 19.04, zooming, ubuntu-budgie

I can't remember what version of ubuntu i used 3 or 4 years ago,
but it had a feature where i could zoom in and zoom out the whole desktop with the mousewheele, like MAC does(i don't know if they can do it with mouse wheel, but it can be activated with mousepad shortcuts)
and i don't know how to do that in **ubuntu budgie**.
PS: My current ubuntu version is: *Budgie 19.04*

Comment: Exactly this! I'm looking for the same feature. Instead, there is this lousy loupe that shows a little part of the screen covering another important part of the screen and very choppy displaying content.